# Passing the value to be used in $_post in PHP/SQL with no predefined value in it

Tags: php

I am making an appointment booking website!
I managed to create a calendar using php which updates automatically.
Now, the slots that are visible are all buttons of form with each one corresponding to one form.

[image]

If the user click on one of the buttons i want a data to be written in a sql database.
The `name` of the button tag is automatically chosen as `date slot` (for eg `2013-7-23 2:00 - 3:00 PM` ). If user clicks a button I will check `$_POST['date slot']` and insert the  entry with username in the database.
**Could anyone please help me out with this?**

**My solution till now** is to generate various if loop in the form submitted php file automatically each day. But i have the concern that it may slow down the process since the program has to go through number_of_days*number_of_slots if loop for each query OR maybe not. Can anyone confirm this? Will it make the Website Slow?
**EDIT** : I looked at the jquery post option mentioned in the comment, The problem is still the same (I think!! doesn't understand fully maybe). Let me rephrase: the name tag of the form is dynamic that is it set's up according to the date and changes everyday.
For example if you look at the [answer of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example) the php file argument `$bar = $_POST['bar'];`the bar is a fixed quantity in which the value is stored and known by the user, but in my case it is changing, though i know the range so i have to right again many if loops. The question is how to avoid this.

Comment: have you looked into jQuery/AJAX/POST logic making use of onclick event or something ?

Comment: @Maximus2012 Thank You for the comment. I am a novice in web development languages. I am learning these things on the need basis.
It would be helpful if you can point me towards a tutorial maybe !! I have no clue about it.. Thank you.  @.icodebuster---thanks for adding Image i could not do it due to bad reputation !!